# Maven Project Organization

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, maven, gruntjs

I am trying to create module within an existing multi-module maven project. This module will require Grunt, Bower, NPM, Angular JS, bootstrap among others. The output of this project (after the build is done) are static resources (fonts, js-files, application-js, application-css).

There is a separate Web module within the project that hosts the Web-Application portion of the Application.

I need to accomplish the following

1. Ensure that Maven can kick of the build of Grunt/Bower based UI Module.
2. Ensure that this module can be plugged in as a dependency for the Web Module.

So far, I have been able to figure out how to include a UI module as a dependency for a Web Project (via WEB-INF/lib/ui.jar...servlet 3.0 spec related).

**Question:**

What should the structure of the project be like to ensure that I don't copy unnecessary files into the JAR (like package.json or node_modules folder)?
Is there a way Maven can do an incremental build on such a project?

I am finding it hard to reconcile the two different project structures due to my own shortcomings I guess.